# Can I use an ASP.NET HttpHandler to create canonical URLs for Classic ASP pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a website that's in Classic ASP on a hosted server. I'd like to be able to create some "virtual" pages so I can specify google-friendly URLs that translate to ASPs

eg www.example.com/this_is_the_help_page

instead of www.example.com/admin/helpsubsystem/help.aspx?current_user etc

As the server also supports ASP.NET - could I use an HTTP Handler to intercept these calls and do any necessary translations?

M

Answer (score 0):

I probably could have done this if I had been keen enough to google it and write it but instead used the wonderful IISrewrite component from Helicon Tech ;)